# passing two parameter in form cant seem to figue out

Tags: php, forms, laravel, parameters

Basically I have an event ID and User ID i need to pass in the form to store... however when i hit create it comes up with

Route pattern "/roles/{id}/{{id}}" cannot reference variable name "id" more than once.

However if i hit enter in the URL bar it works... so not to sure whats happening here... help would be greatful here the code.

Route file

```
// POST Add Users Race
Route::post('racehistory/{event_id}/store/{user_id}/race/', 'racehistoryController@store'); 

// GET Current Races
Route::get('events/currentRace', 'racingeventController@viewCurrentRace');

// GET Users 
Route::get('events/{event_id}/users', 'racingeventController@users');

// GET Users with Group ID
Route::get('events/{event_id}/{group_id}', 'racingeventController@grouped');

// GET Add Users Race Form
Route::get('events/{event_id}/user/{user_id}/addrace', 'racingeventController@addUserRace');

// Add User to Event
Route::get('events/{event_id}/user/{user_id}', 'racingeventController@addUserToEvent');

// DELETE Remove User from Race Event
Route::get('events/{event_id}/delete/user/{user_id}', 'racingeventController@deleteUserToEvent');

// DELETE Race Event
Route::get('events/delete/{event_id}', 'racingeventController@destroy');

Route::resource('events', 'racingeventController');
```

Form View

```
{{ Form::open(array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'method' => 'post', 'action' => array('racehistoryController@store', $user->id, $event->id))) }}
```

Controller - racehistoryController

```
public function store($event_id, $user_id)
{
    $rules = array(
        'start_event'   => 'required',
        'end_event'     => 'required',
        'pool_type'     => 'required|max:3|min:3',
        'name'          => 'required|max:35|min:3',
        'location'      => 'required|max:35|min:3',
    );

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return 'form works';
    }
}
```

Comment: give the whole route file. you are referencing one param more than once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Name your route:

```php
Route::get(
    'racehistory/{event_id}/store/{user_id}/race/',
    ['as' => 'store', 'uses' => 'racehistoryControlle@store']
);
```

2. Fix `Form::open()` helper:

```php
{{ 
    Form::open([
        'class' => 'form-horizontal', 
        'method' => 'post', 
        'route' => ['store', $user->id, $event->id]
    ]) 
}}
```

Comment: ahh yes... and ive changed the rout to post rather than get ??? ... as i realise that im posting it not geting

Comment: @levilucas your English is pretty bad, try to pay more attention to spelling when writing comments.

Comment: Sorry it's a bad habit i know but i manage to do the above and change the route to a post rather than a get and its seems to be fine now.... Looking at my routes file would you say this is the correct way as i feel once i get deeper into the application i'm making there is gonna be loads of routes at this rate?

Comment: seems OK to me, but you can still improve it by using routing groups: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#route-groups